# VB.NET - Wait till event is finished

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a fast example program of what i'm trying to accomplish. The program gets a process and enables it to raise events. I'm especially looking at the Process.Exited event. It will be fired when the process is terminated.

Now if the process gets terminated the event fires and i want to restart the process and "relink" it to the object. But if in the meantime the mainthread wants to access the process it will crash, because the process hasn't restarted.

Is there a way to wait till the Process.Exited event is finished executing and stop all other code while it's running?

```
Public Class MyProcess
    Public Proc As Process

    Public Sub New(P As Process)
        'Initalize the process
        Me.Proc = P
        Me.Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler Proc.Exited, AddressOf ProcClosed
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcClosed()
        'Restart the process and wait till it's started
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you re-creating a new instance of MyProcess everytime you want to restart a program?

Comment: No i reuse the object

Comment: Okay, i'm not sure where your code will crash in that case..

Comment: Once you create a `Process` you can call `WaitForInputIdle` but it won;t always behave as you may expect and not at all for apps that don't wait for user input.

Comment: @Sasha the crash is not that relevant. I just want to stop all other code running and resume it when ProcClosed is finished executing

Comment: You can just use a boolean and toggle it when you're restarting the process and when the process restart is finished

Comment: In a small program that would be an easy solution. But to add an "if(Boolean) Then do sth" for every line in the program is not ideal.

Comment: You can trnsform you class in `Public Class MyProcess Inherits Process`, passing `FileName` and `Arguments` in the costructor. Then, as jmcilhinney suggested, you can use `WaitForInputIdle()`, both after the first `Start()` and in the `Exited` event to start/restart the Process. Mind that you really want to start a Windowed process. A non-windowed process, if errors out or otherwise closes immediatly, will lock the machine (will be restarted non-stop). I suggest to use UI Automation to detect when a process Window (graphics UI or Console) is started or closed and take whatever action needed.